# Getting a NullPointerException trying a simple example of partial mocking with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to implement a simple example of partial mocking. Running the test below I keep getting a `NullPointerException` ERDP.myFunction on the first line of the method. Any idea why?

```
public class ErdpTest{
  
  private Erdp erdp = null;
  
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    erdp = mock(Erdp.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyFunctionTrue() {
    when(erdp.myFunction()).thenCallRealMethod();
    assertTrue(erdp.myFunction());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm more concerned by the fact that `private ERDPerdp = null;` compiles.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that line is not syntactically valid. Even after your edit.

Comment: add above the test class `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: Sorry, I hope now it's syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spy` for partial mocking.
Here is some code:
`erdp = spy(new Erdp.class);`

You can mock methods in a `spy` via the same methods you use to mock methods in a `mock`.

The key difference between a `spy` and a `mock` is that a mock is just a proxy and all methods return null by default.  With a spy, all methods call the real method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public class ErdpTest {

    private Erdp erdp = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        erdp = mock(Erdp.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyFunctionTrue() {
        doCallRealMethod().when(erdp).myFunction();
        assertTrue(erdp.myFunction());
    }
}
```